# ActionScript Game - Missing parts

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am making a game in ActionScript and it's basically an asteroids type game. 
When it is played, the enemy which is the rocks, don't appear on screen.
It's quite a big problem, and if anyone can solve it id be very grateful.

I'll provide links to download the files as there is too much code to place in here.

Thanks.

TweenLite.as (Needs to be placed in a folder called "gs"

[TweenLite Download](http://www.mediafire.com/?ku8x1aiwv3h9933)

[Bullet.as Download](http://www.mediafire.com/?yp6pu1ys9im0asm)

[Enemy.as Download](http://www.mediafire.com/?gbxuvcrv2bebyga)

[The main flash file](http://www.mediafire.com/?qy4dopjjz5ud5ba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing brace on line 93 of the script in the Flash file. So the code to add the enemies only runs if the condition of the unclosed brace is true.

To balance the braces you'll need to remove the closing brace on line 109.

Comment: Thank you for that, worked great. Its always the simple things.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code here's a pretty standard method of placing items on the stage via AS3

```
/* 
this code places an instance of the asteroid_mc into the variable asteroid so that it can be instantiated onto the stage with addChild and positioned using the .x and .y 
*/

var asteroid:asteroid_mc = asteroid_mc();
addChild(asteroid);
asteroid.x = 200;
asteroid.y = 100;
```

Comment: I have similar code in there, I have discovered that the enemy will appear when the spaceship controlled by the user is off the screen. so I am lost as to why this happens now.